# Прогрессбар не обновляется при распаковке архива с помощью JSZip

Tags: javascript

Мне приходится загружать большой архив на страницу и для пользователя необходимо выводить прогресс его распаковки. Функция `updateCallback` должна изменять длину прогрессбара `<div class='bar' />` и дополнительно логировать прогресс в консоль. С логированием всё ок, а вот длина `.bar` не меняется, видимо потому что страница виснет целиком и по-этому не обновляется.

Вот примерный код:

```
JSZip
    .loadAsync(arraybuffer)
    .then(function (zip) {
        return zip.file("example.txt").async("ArrayBuffer",function updateCallback(metadata) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("bar")[0].style.width = metadata.percent + "%";
            console.log(metadata.percent);
        });
    })
```

Подскажите какой-нибудь выход из ситуации, я знаю, он должен быть =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поискал ещё немного, прочёл про *потоки* и нашел ответ, надеюсь ещё кому-нибудь пригодится.

Код распаковки архива заменяем на:

```
if (window.Worker) {
    worker = new Worker("unzipFile.js");
    worker.onmessage = function(event){ 
        if (event.data.type == 'ready') 
            console.log(event.data.content); /*файл готов, можно обрабатывать*/
        else document.getElementsByClassName("bar")[0].style.width = event.data.percent;
    };
    worker.postMessage({content: data, filename: 'example.txt'});
} else { /* здесь оставляем как было для счастливых пользователей IE10- */}
```

Создаём там же файл unzipFile.js и заполняем следующим кодом:

```
self.importScripts('/js/jszip.min.js');
onmessage = function(event){
    JSZip
        .loadAsync(event.data.content)
        .then(function (zip) {
            zip.file(event.data.filename).async("ArrayBuffer",function (metadata) {
                postMessage({ type: 'progress', percent: metadata.percent + "%" });
            })
            .then(function (data){
                postMessage({ type: 'ready', content: data });
            });
        });
}
```